# Why can't singular values be complex numbers?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, singular-values

Reading both [this paper](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs322/2008sp/stuff/TrefethenBau_Lec4_SVD.pdf) (p. 4) and the Wikipedia article regarding singular value decomposition, they state that the diagonal matrix ${\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}$ in  $$\mathbf {M} =\mathbf {U} {\boldsymbol {\Sigma }}\mathbf {V} ^{*}$$ has non-negative **real** entries in a context where the general field is assumed to be $\mathbb{C}$. My question is: why can't singular values be complex?

Comment: You forgot to put *nonnegative* in bold too. There's no such thing as a nonnegative complex number that isn't real.

Answer (score 6):

The singular values in $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ are by definition the nonnegative square roots eigenvalues of the matrix $\mathbf{M}^{\dagger}\mathbf{M}$. This matrix is Hermitian and nonnegative-definite, and hence has nonnegative real eigenvalues:

Let $A$ be Hermitian and nonnegative-definite. Then the eigenvalues are real and nonnegative.

**Proof:** Let $x$ be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$. Then
$$ x^{\dagger} A x = \lambda x^{\dagger} x = \lambda \lVert x \rVert^2. $$
Taking the conjugate,
$$ (x^{\dagger} A x)^{*} = x^{\dagger} A^{\dagger} x = x^{\dagger}Ax, $$
and hence $x^{\dagger} A x - (x^{\dagger}Ax)^*$ vanishes, which can only occur if this number is real. Since $\lVert x \rVert^2$ is real, $\lambda$ is the quotient of two real numbers and so is real.

The definition of nonnegative-definite is that $x^{\dagger} A x \geq 0$ for all $x$, so $\lambda \lVert x \rVert^2 \geq 0$, and $\lVert x \rVert^2$ is nonnegative, so $\lambda$ must also be nonnegative. $\square$

Comment: Why do you use the pseudoinverse? Is that just another notation for the conjugate transpose?

Comment: $\mathbf{M}^{\dagger}$ is standard notation for the [conjugate transpose/adjoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose) (i.e. $(\mathbf{M}^T)^*$.

Comment: Apparently in quantum mechanics $M^\dagger$ is standard notation for the conjugate transpose of $M$, but I think in math $M^*$ is standard notation for the conjugate transpose of $M$.

Comment: I think in my university's undergraduate mathematics course, the adjoint of a complex matrix is denoted exclusively by $M^{\dagger}$. Sometimes one does take the complex conjugate of a matrix without transposing it!

Comment: Yes seems to be some confusion, I have also seen $^*$ used for conjugate transpose.

Comment: I never saw $M^\dagger$. Surely $M^*$ and $M^H$ are the usual [notation in  maths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix)

Comment: What if a matrix for which we wat to calculate singular values is not Hermitian, i.e. just a general square matrix? Such a general square matrix can have negative and/or complex eigenvalues.  Do we still define singular values as the square root of these eigenvalues in this case?  Thank you.